# timestamp IDs that are guaranteed to increment

Tags: mysql

I can set the primary key as a timestamp accurate to seconds. But it works as intended only when new rows are inserted a minimum of 1 second apart. I can increase the resolution to microseconds, but I wonder if it's overkill and slow stuff down.

I want timestamps since they are easy to sort on time but I don't care about prescription greater than a second.

What is a good way to generate them?

Comment: An auto incrementing key will also be in insertion order and is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Best way is not to do it at all -- just use a sequential autonumbered ID field like everyone else. Fine, have a separate timestamp field, but don't use it as your ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what queries you expect to process.

You can actually use both `TIMESTAMP` and some surrogate primary key; the latter would be auto_incremented, as usual, and the former may be indexed over as well for some sorting queries:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (
  sometable_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  ts TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (sometable_id),
  KEY (ts)
);
```

... or you can drop the surrogate key altogether and go without `PRIMARY KEY` -w With a single `INDEX` over `TIMESTAMP` column (remember, `INDEX` != `UNIQUE`).

I would use the first approach, though; it's more flexible and extensible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want MySQL generate automatically the time stamp, you can define a timestamp column with a default value while still using an AUTO INCREMENT number as the primary key:

```
create temporary table tbl (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    ts timestamp default current_timestamp
    -- other columns follow...
);
```

To insert new data, just omit values for `id` and `ts`:

```
insert into tbl values ();

select * from tbl;
+----+---------------------+
| id | ts                  |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2012-09-20 18:24:21 |
+----+---------------------+
```

Be sure to define an index on the timestamp column if you are frequently searching or ordering by it...